# xslt for xml from dataset

Tags: .net, xslt

I have the following data format in my dataset. I need to come out with an xml using xslt. I have tried with some xslt stuff which does not works. An example can help me a lot.

I am tried following link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fd7xytc.aspx

My dataset

```
name    color   city
====    =====   ====
rice    white   city1
rice    white   City2
```

My required xml output

```
<xml>

<name>  rice    </name>

<color> White   </color>

<cities>        

<city>  city1   </city>

<city>  city2   </city>

</cities>       

</xml>
```

Comment: So, what is the XML document on which the transformation is supposed to operate? Please, *edit* the question and provide this missing, important information.

Comment: Could you show us what the DataSet's XML looks like?  You can access this by accessing the `OuterXml` property of the `XmlDataDocument` object.  Also, what XSLT have you tried so far and is your data guaranteed to have only one `name` and `color` across all rows (like in your example where they're all "rice" and "white"?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this will work.  If you can show us your input XML, I can verify and refine this answer:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xml>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]/name | *[1]/color"/>
      <cities>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*/city" />
      </cities>
    </xml>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*/*/*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```